# Obtain pod labels of kubernetes deployment

Tags: go, kubernetes, yaml

I'm trying to write code in Go to fetch the labels of the pods created in a deployment. For example:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.14.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

I know if I use ObjectMeta, I would be able to fetch the metadata of the deployment, but I would not be able to fetch the spec. Is there a way to get the data from the spec level of the resource?

Comment: Add your code in the question

Answer (score 0):

Using [kubernetes client-go](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go) and [this example](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/master/examples/out-of-cluster-client-configuration/main.go) I was able to get the labels for each container

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "path/filepath"

    metav1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
    "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes"
    "k8s.io/client-go/tools/clientcmd"
    "k8s.io/client-go/util/homedir"
)

func main() {
    var kubeconfig *string
    if home := homedir.HomeDir(); home != "" {
        kubeconfig = flag.String("kubeconfig", filepath.Join(home, ".kube", "config"), "(optional) absolute path to the kubeconfig file")
    } else {
        kubeconfig = flag.String("kubeconfig", "", "absolute path to the kubeconfig file")
    }
    flag.Parse()

    // use the current context in kubeconfig
    config, err := clientcmd.BuildConfigFromFlags("", *kubeconfig)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf(err.Error())
    }

    // create the clientset
    clientset, err := kubernetes.NewForConfig(config)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf(err.Error())
    }

  // get pods
    pods, err := clientset.CoreV1().Pods("your-namespace").List(context.TODO(), metav1.ListOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf(err.Error())
    }

  // get labels
  for _, pod := range pods.Items {
    labels := pod.GetObjectMeta().GetLabels()
    fmt.Printf("%+v", labels)
  }
}
```